# jsf commandLink set style class for anchor

Tags: jsf, commandlink, trinidad

I have a commandLink in my JSF page, which renders an anchor properly. How can I set a style class for the anchor element ?

Comment: Please take a step back and read some basic tutorials... And did you honestly not find an answer somewhere on the internet about such a basic thing. And what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="my-css-class" ... \>
```

Comment: I tried that. But that doesn't set the class on the anchor element.

Comment: What does the source of the rendered HTML look like for the anchor?